# What makes an Android app re-installable?

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

Through Eclipse I can easily re-install (*without* having to uninstall the app first), a small app I am currently developing, any change any number of times.

When I export that app ("release mode") and place it on a website, it downloads and installs without any problem. (I have to check "Unknown sources" for allowing installation of non-Market apps first, of course).

If I uninstall this app, then download it again and install it again, it installs without any problem.

However, if I try to re-install this app without uninstalling it first, then Android notifies that the installation failed.

My question is why? What makes an Android app re-installable? (i.e. without having to uninstall it first, thus losing its existing settings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot replace a signed application with an unsigned one.

Comment: This makes sense. Can I replace an unsigned application with a signed one? (i.e. the opposite direction)

Answer (score 0):

You fail to install it because it has the same app version. If you recompile it and then download it, it will update, because the version will have changed.